# Как использовать SDK для .NET с поддержкой .NET 6.0?

Tags: c#, sdk, кроссплатформенность, rider, avalonia

Создал крослатформенное решение на Avalonia:

`dotnet new -i avalonia.templates`

При попытке запуска на каждом проекте выходит сообщение:

> Microsoft.NET.TargetFrameworkInference.targets(141, 5): [NETSDK1045] текущий пакет SDK для .NET не поддерживает целевой объект .NET 6.0. Выберите .NET 5.0 или более раннюю версию либо используйте версию пакета SDK для .NET, которая поддерживает .NET 6.0.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Установлены следующие SDK Tools (правда, непонятно, что из этого нужно для поддержки .NET 6.0):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А правый клик на решении > Manage .NET SDK даёт следующее:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что нужно доустановить из SDK-инструментов, и нужно ли их где-то отдельно прописывать в проекте или решении?

Comment: Зачем вы вообще в android полезли? Проблема точно не там.

Comment: Попробуйте .net 6 sdk найти и поставить.

Comment: И приведите содержимое своего файла проекта (.csproj)

Comment: @PavelMayorov какого именно, их 5 (общий, Android, iOS, Desktop, Web)?

Comment: Того, в котором возникает ошибка

Comment: @PavelMayorov эта ошибка возникает во всех проектах

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вначале нужно понять, какие .NET SDK установлены в системе:

```
$ dotnet --list-sdks
5.0.202 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
6.0.402 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
7.0.100 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
```

Если нет SDK минимально требуемой версии - доустановить.

Затем в корневом каталоге решения в файле `global.json` указать нужную версию SDK, причём точь в точь, как в полученном списке:

```
{
  "sdk": {
    "version": "6.0.402",
    "rollForward": "disable",
    "allowPrerelease": true
  },
  "msbuild-sdks": {
    "Microsoft.Build.Traversal": "1.0.43",
    "Xamarin.Legacy.Sdk": "0.1.2-alpha6",
    "MSBuild.Sdk.Extras": "3.0.22",
    "AggregatePackage.NuGet.Sdk": "0.1.12"
  }
}
```